# JavaScript Object - Find one property -> change to true and change all others to false

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can shorten this bit of code and logic? This code is currently very long.  Maybe there is something I can do with map, hash or whatever?

As you can see, I have an object with 7 properties. I want an easy way of changing one `target` property to `true` and all 6 others to `false`.

```
 var object = {
        a: false,
        b: false,
        c: false,
        d: false,
        e: false,
        f: false,
        g: false
    }

    target = "b";

    switch(target) {
        case a:
            object.a = true;
            object.b = false;
            object.c = false;
            object.d = false;
            object.e = false;
            object.f = false;
            object.g = false;
            break;
        case b:
            object.a = false;
            object.b = true;
            object.c = false;
            object.d = false;
            object.e = false;
            object.f = false;
            object.g = false;
            break;
        case c:
            object.a = false;
            object.b = false;
            object.c = true;
            object.d = false;
            object.e = false;
            object.f = false;
            object.g = false;
            break
        case d:
            object.a = false;
            object.b = false;
            object.c = false;
            object.d = true;
            object.e = false;
            object.f = false;
            object.g = false;
            break;
        case e:
            object.a = false;
            object.b = false;
            object.c = false;
            object.d = false;
            object.e = true;
            object.f = false;
            object.g = false;
            break
        case f:
            object.a = false;
            object.b = false;
            object.c = false;
            object.d = false;
            object.e = false;
            object.f = true;
            object.g = false;
            break;
        case g:
            object.a = false;
            object.b = false;
            object.c = false;
            object.c = false;
            object.d = false;
            object.e = false;
            object.f = false;
            object.g = true;
            break;
    }
```

**How can I set the property given in `target` to `true`, while setting the other 6 to `false`?**

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple loop over the keys and set each one to false/true if it matches

```js
var myObject = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false
}


function updateState (active) {
  Object.keys(myObject).forEach( function (key) {
    myObject[key] = key === active
  })
}


/*
const updateState = active => 
  Object.keys(myObject).forEach( key =>
    myObject[key] = key === active
  )
*/

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))
updateState('b')
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))
updateState('c')
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

Comment: Is it neccessary in most cases to JSON stringify? i ask cause, i come across this issue alot and going forward i would be using your example.  thanks again

Comment: JSON.stringify was just to show that it changed in the console output. Has nothing to do with changing the value.

Comment: thanks epascarello, that clears it up for me.  you have yourself a good one!

Answer (score 2):

Simply set all values to false, then set the value you want to true:

```js
var object = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: false,
  e: false,
  f: false,
  g: false
}

target = "b";
for (var prop in object) {
  object[prop] = false;
}

object[target] = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused. Your object has all properties already set to false. Is the assumption that this object will not always have all properties set to false? If so this would be my approach.

```
var object = {
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false,
    d: false,
    e: false,
    f: false,
    g: false
}

target = "b";

object = _.mapValues(object, () => false);

object[target] = true;
```

Comment: in the beginning of the program, one will be true, the rest false.  so we can say a will be true at beginning

Comment: Ok great. The code I posted should work perfectly for you. The _.mapValues method is more efficient than running a loop and its a nice little one-liner.

Comment: "The _.mapValues method is more efficient than running a loop " HOW is it more efficient.... under the covers it is looping, you are not doing the looping yourself.

Comment: @epascarello good call and I apologize, I meant to say because instead of and. map has a callback that actually gives it more overhead than a for loop. I'll side with it being more efficient than a foreach, but marginally so. Still, I appreciate the one-line nature of the map approach. But you are correct and I misspoke.

Comment: That code is using a callback for setting false. `() => false` so every iteration that call is executing that function to return false

Comment: Yea isn't that what I just said?

Answer (score 1):

```
var object = {
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false,
    d: false,
    e: false,
    f: false,
    g: false
}
target = "b";
Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
  object[key] = false
})
object[target] = true
```